# Getting this message in mist: Couldn't estimate gas, resorting to default parameters. Transaction is likely cheaper than the estimate

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, mist, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp

What is this error message in red:

```
Couldn't estimate gas, resorting to default parameters. 
Transaction is likely cheaper than the estimate
```

[image: What is this error message in red]

I have written a smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract MyFirstContract {
    uint256 counter =0;

    function increase() public {
        counter++;
    }

    function  decrease() public{
        counter--;
    }

    function getCounter() public constant  returns (uint256) {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

At the time of contact creation, it has estimated 77,829 gas and I set the maximum gas to 877,829.

When I execute a function on the contract, why do I get this error message in red?

Kindly guide me as I am a beginner in Ethereum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue in my Ethereum wallet and i couldn't even transfer ether between accounts. Later I found that this is an issue with the version of my Ethereum Wallet which was v0.11.0. Then when I changed into v0.9.3, it worked fine.

Comment: thanks, it helped me but the problem was in mist wallet now i am using ethereum wallet 0.11.0 and its working fine

Comment: I am glad that it helped you.... :)